# converting the object to array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to convert array object to object in javascript.

I have a array object `arrobj` which i want to display the others field.

```
var arrobj =[{
    "id": "1",
    "others": {
      "desc": "sample",
      "fields": "sevice"
    }
  }]

// converting `others` object to array  object
function obj(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj.others).reduce((arr, key)=>{
              const subObj = {[key]: obj.others[key]};
              return arr.concat(subObj)
          }, []);
}

var result = this.obj(arrobj);
<div>
 {
   result.map(e=>
     Description:<div>result.desc</div>
     Fields: <div>result.fields</div>
  )
 }
</div>

Expected Output

Description: sample
Fields: service
```

Comment: I wonder what "array object" is

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [{
    id: "1",
    others: {
        desc: "sample",
        fields: "service"
    }
}, {
    id: "1",
    others: {
        desc: "sample",
        fields: "service"
    }
}];

const result = arrayOfObjects.map(e => e.others);
```